# "Invalid OAuth Access Token - Cannot Parse Access Token" Error when Creating Facebook Campaign using Facebook Ad API

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to create a Facebook campaign using the Facebook Ad API in my Node.js application. However, I keep encountering the error "Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token" when attempting to create the campaign.

I have included the necessary fields such as the access token, app secret, app ID, ad account ID, and campaign ID. Despite passing these values correctly, I am unable to resolve the issue.Here is the relevant code snippet that pertains to the campaign creation:
Campaign.js:

```
'use strict';
const bizSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-business-sdk');
const AdAccount = bizSdk.AdAccount;
const { AdsInsights, Campaign } = bizSdk;
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const access_token = '';
const app_secret = '<App secret>';
const app_id = '<app_Id>';
const showDebugingInfo = true; 
const ad_account_id = '<Ad_Account_Id>'; 
const campaign_id = '<YOUR_CAMPAIGN_ID>'; 
const api = bizSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token);

if (showDebugingInfo) {
  api.setDebug(true);
}

const logApiCallResult = (apiCallName, data) => {
  console.log(apiCallName);
  if (showDebugingInfo) {
    console.log('Data:' + JSON.stringify(data));
  }
};

router.get('/getcampaign', (req, res) => {
  const fields = [
    AdsInsights.Fields.impressions,
    AdsInsights.Fields.inlineLinkClicks,
    AdsInsights.Fields.spend,
  ];

  const params = {
    'time_range': {'since': 'yesterday', 'until': 'today'},
  };

  const campaign = new Campaign(campaign_id, ad_account_id);
  campaign.getInsights(fields, params)
    .then((insights) => {
      res.json(insights);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    });
});

router.post('/createcampaign', (req, res) => {
  const AdAccount = new bizSdk.AdAccount(ad_account_id);
  const campaign = new Campaign(null, ad_account_id);
  const campaignParams = {
    name: 'My Campaign', 
    objective: 'LINK_CLICKS', 
    status: 'PAUSED', 
    special_ad_categories: ['NONE'], 
  };

  AdAccount.createCampaign([], campaignParams, { access_token: access_token })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Campaign created successfully: ', result);
      res.json({ success: true, campaignId: result._data.id });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error creating campaign: ', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    });
});

router.post('/updatecampaign', (req, res) => {
  const campaign = new Campaign(campaign_id, ad_account_id);
  const campaignParams = {
    name: 'Updated Campaign Name', 
    status: 'PAUSED',
  };

  campaign
    .update(campaignParams)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Campaign updated successfully: ', result);
      res.json({ success: true });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error updating campaign: ', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js:

```
const http = require("http")
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const facebookRoute = require('../Mediation/Service/FacebookAdService');
const campaignRoutes = require('./Campaign');
const adsetRoutes = require('./Adset');


app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

app.use('/FacebookAdService', facebookRoute);
app.use('/', adsetRoutes);
app.use('/', campaignRoutes);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error("Not Found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here's the response i am getting in postman after i am passing the token in the header and passing the body:

```
{
    
  "id": "353365098746250",
  "name": "test campaign",
  "objective": "LINK_CLICKS",
  "status": "PAUSED",
  "special_ad_categories": ["NONE"]
}
```

The response i am getting:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "FacebookRequestError",
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token",
        "stack": "Error\n    at FacebookRequestError.FacebookError [as constructor] (D:\\Work\\Mediation\\node_modules\\facebook-nodejs-business-sdk\\dist\\cjs.js:349:16)\n    at new FacebookRequestError (D:\\Work\\Mediation\\node_modules\\facebook-nodejs-business-sdk\\dist\\cjs.js:371:129)\n    at D:\\Work\\Mediation\\node_modules\\facebook-nodejs-business-sdk\\dist\\cjs.js:674:15\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "status": 400,
        "response": {
            "message": "Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 190,
            "fbtrace_id": "AVX0udiCC95QfUIH1ZR33Dk"
        },
        "headers": {
            "vary": "Origin",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "www-authenticate": "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_token\" \"Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token\"",
            "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000; preload",
            "pragma": "no-cache",
            "cache-control": "no-store",
            "expires": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT",
            "x-fb-request-id": "AVX0udiCC95QfUIH1ZR33Dk",
            "x-fb-trace-id": "AIVKNxkEDHh",
            "x-fb-rev": "1009526237",
            "x-fb-debug": "DEBurJXzasFL/gEcCZVr97F+HNa+Huqz7KW6qXF9EQxsRxUy97A5cQxmHGNWAQa1+ODwY/wa7m+W1QirkjjQDg==",
            "date": "Fri, 27 Oct 2023 10:54:37 GMT",
            "proxy-status": "http_request_error; e_clientaddr=\"AcIRXs3NId91_20G1RU7DBnxE8hlCHlzkZ7ioVmlDsuY8rSJSJliA1_N5tYJzfDWIL-s6uojcxK8JUgawA\"; e_fb_vipport=\"AcK-A9kQCHDVu2WeUUTR1zLySpH0ApNqj2d-_KduAggRtMRpeGCZTWBdereb\"; e_upip=\"AcKrXWXYTdRyWEO7rV2WjRz0pgdSZaPR-FNdiRH3LOKRzQuvJS-_c5oaTB-ojeBO7FELylvYetRAMs-lrRhH9bp0EIhsuGRlUg\"; e_fb_hostheader=\"AcJiEPQOpPUY1XutmWb5W6VKtYRtkGO4cW3CNZOGuKWw990wckTAdFWjjIhrSdpSq-bzGSWsqy7dK3jN\"; e_fb_vipaddr=\"AcKc5wNx4AhQ6MY1mfFXV8IcDAIX2LEjRYJwGVAOonO4ElVHNilWGtw4mmqorEgMo5dpEbAXyoE\"; e_fb_requesthandler=\"AcIKY4AjVqFnigXCwt3gT02vDgncdtkQYLBooURi-gYlzVPihc53QtiAjYnDuKqX-nC4WhYWMxI\"; e_fb_builduser=\"AcLChMilUMvwB1SrwgUddWV6dXyJ6gvTF-MerV69MWkybwjMSL6AgvSss6dCRhDavs4\"; e_fb_binaryversion=\"AcKXLNo1u3eSywrgTI_uWMlvoI_e1LxSsCfFIQSDVznYCXbBSnK0JFb57Zv27h5v9J9QNLrk_aauWgLWAlxNgUj9K7HYNr2UvuI\"; e_proxy=\"AcL5olnCd6aeWWDfv9UdNoHmoDZuiMQVDkzOvPs3MOaorQwfLS5vrNrKI-6dhE_JLxyACUgr6D7zO_Q2\"",
            "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=86400",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "content-length": "152"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0?access_token=%3CACCESS_TOKEN%3E",
        "data": {
            "name": "My Campaign",
            "objective": "LINK_CLICKS",
            "status": "PAUSED",
            "special_ad_categories": [
                "NONE"
            ],
            "id": "353365098746250"
        }
    }
}
```

```
I have verified that the access token is generated from Meta for developers and is being passed in the Authorization header.
I have checked that the app secret, app ID, ad account ID, and campaign ID are accurate and correctly passed to the API.
```

Any insights or suggestions on why this error is occurring and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).